# Is it possible to submit Chrome extension for review without automatically publishing it using Chrome Webstore API?

Tags: chrome-web-store

Is it possible to submit Chrome extension for review without publishing it automatically using Chrome Webstore API? The [publish endpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/#trustedtesters) submits the package for review and automatically publishes it after it had passed the review, but it is desirable to be able to manually publish the extension.
Basically, is it possible to achieve the same result as by unchecking the checkbox on the popup window seen on the screenshot? 
[Submit for review confirmation window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KN8O.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible so far as you can see from the doc [Publishing Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/webstore_api/items/publish/). What you can do is to publish it just for a tester (closed group) and once you're sure publish to another time publicly. That way you can control it via the dashboard.